# Where can I find documentation about nodes npx command?

Tags: node.js, npx

Searching for **npx** leads me to this npx repo

https://github.com/npm/npx#readme

which says "DEPRECATED: This project has been deprecated - npx is now part of the npm cli"

following the given link to npm I cannot find anything about npx.

Where is npx documented nowadays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npx/). It's part of the CLI now, but the command is still aliased under `npx`.